# Python pandas - want to use values in both cols hitting road block

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Trying to use both values of T and V from a 2 column text file (iterating over all rows) to pass to other functions

**SourceFile**

```
T1|V1
T2|V2
T3|V3
```

**Output**

```
T1:1    V1
Name: T1, dtype: object
T2:1    V2
Name: T1, dtype: object
T3:1    V3
Name: T3, dtype: object
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
dfcsv = pd.read_csv("mycsv.txt" , delimiter = '|', header=None, index_col=0) 
df = pd.DataFrame(dfcsv)
for t,v in df.iterrows():
    T = str(t)
    V = str(v)
    print (T+":"+V)`
```

Comment: `reset_index`, then `df[0]+':'+df[1]`

Comment: In your case, `V` is a Series, you probably want `V.iloc[0]`

Comment: Thank you @mozway - Your second suggestion worked perfectly.

First suggestion appeared to make T the rownumber (i.e. index)

Comment: You're welcome but why are your using `iterrows`? This is most often a bad practice